# UIWebView in UIView need links to open up in browser

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

So i have an app that is not so much a webapp but more uses UIViewControllers and UIViews for most screens.  On one particular controller i have a UIWebView control that only occupies a small portion of the UIViewController screen real estate that i load html from a web service as a string.

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:marketingBlurb baseURL:nil];
```

what i'm wondering is if the html links in this string can open up on the browser and not in the UIWebView in my app????  How can i do this??  Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the delegate of the webview to **self**, and intercept all links using **webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:**

You can then call [UIApplication openURL] to open Safari.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

I didn't test this code, but it will get you started.